# wordpress plugins - sticky news footer bar

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am looking for a plugin that scroll text (better from posts) at the end of the page (but sticky footer, news style with links).
I have been used Ditty News Ticker plugin and some developer made customisation in the plugin code to make it work, after an update, it overrun the code and now I cannot see actually anything.
so if you know good plugin or a way to fix the problem it would be very helpful!

thanks.
david

Comment: See the New User Tour - SO is not for recommendation questions. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Before posting your next question please, go to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then, if you are sure your question fits the SO rules, read [How to Ask a question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be able to make a useful, well formed and on-topic question.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [Page scroll to id](https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-scroll-to-id/) plugin. **Page scroll to id** is a fully featured plugin which replaces browser’s “jumping” behavior with a smooth scrolling animation.